# Icons not showing properly in Yosemite's Safari favourites bar

Tags: macos, safari, icon

In this picture you can see that Safari recognises the correct icon for the bookmarks:

[image: Bookmarks]

However when I look at them as part of the drop down menu in the address bar a lot of the icons are missing:

[image: Bookmarks under address bar]

Is there a way to make the address bar refresh and load the proper icons or do I have to manually add the icons. And if so, how do I do it.

I use the address bar non-stop and it would be nice if it could do what it is supposed to do and look a bit more attractive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different icons:

- the ones in the sidebar are *[Favicons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)* icons
- the one in the favourites are Apple specific (only shown by Safari) and called *[Web Clips](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)* (or Apple Touch Icons)

They are both downloaded from the site but can be different.

For example IMDB specifies

- [http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/favicon-2165806970.*CB379387995*.ico](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/favicon-2165806970._CB379387995_.ico) as Favicon and

[image]

- [http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/mobile/apple-touch-icon-web-76x76-53536248.*CB361295462*.png](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/mobile/apple-touch-icon-web-76x76-53536248._CB361295462_.png) as Web Clip

[image]

From the comments: you can add a clip following [these instructions](http://ipod.about.com/od/webbrowsing/ss/Adding-Editing-And-Deleting-Bookmarks-In-Safari.htm):

> To create a webclip, go to the site you want and tap the box-and-arrow icon used to create bookmarks. In the menu that pops up, tap the Add to Home Screen option. Edit the name of the webclip and tap Add. You'll then be taken to your home screen and shown the webclip. Tap it to go to that site.

Comment: If a website does not provide a Web Clip can you set your own web clip for a specific web page?

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple Touch Icons are uploaded alongside the HTML files on the website, usually in the root folder. Safari just pulls them from here if they exist. It is up to the site owner to add them.

Answer (score 0):

Try and clear the icon cache. [Instructions](http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-delete-favicon-caches-from-safari/).